# Ugly java code with xsd:sequence

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I use JAXB to bind XSD schemas to POCOs. I have tried two different ways to write an XSD schema but each has a flaw:

**Option 1**

Problem: Each element is represented with `<Elements>` in XML instead of `<Element>`, plus they are not inside a container such as `<ElementsContainer>`.

*XSD Schema*

```
<xs:element name="Root" type="RootType" />

<xs:complexType name="RootType" />
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Elements" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

*Java*

```
RootType r = new RootType();
r.getElements.add("Str1");
r.getElements.add("Str2");
```

*Marshaled XML*

```
<Root>
  <Elements>Str1</Elements> 
  <Elements>Str2</Elements>
</Root>
```

**Option 2**

Problem: Java code looks uglier.

*XSD Schema*

```
<xs:element name="Root" type="RootType" />

<xs:complexType name="RootType" />
  <xs:element name="Elements">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Element" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
```

*Java*

```
RootType r = new RootType();
r.getElements().getElement().add("Str1");
r.getElements().getElement().add("Str2");
```

*Marshaled XML*

```
<Root>
  <Elements>
    <Element>Str1</Element>
    <Element>Str2</Element>
  </Elements>
</Root>
```

**Question:** Is there a way to write a schema that outputs an XML like in **Option 2** and whose code is written like in **Option 1**?

**Edit:** `<xs:list>` is not an option as elements may have white-spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Starting from Java Classes**

If you are starting from Java Objects you can use the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to add a grouping element.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Elements")
@XmlElement(name="Element)
public List<Element> getElements() {
    return elements;
}
```

**Starting from XML Schemas**

The XJC tool is very extensible.  The following plug-in written for the XJC tool appears to allow you to generate `@XmlElementWrapper` annotations into your model.

- https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin

Comment: I am starting from schemas. I wouldn't prefer to make changes to the code each time I generate POCOs from schemas.

Comment: @mostruash - I have updated my answer with a link that may help.

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer. However, this solution does not seem to produce an XML where `<Element>` tags are inside `<Elements>`. Come to think about it, it might be impossible to do so without auto-generating a custom getter for the POCO.

Comment: @mostruash - I have updated my answer with an example of the JAXB annotations you need to produce the XML that you are looking for.  The standard XJC tool will never generate an `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.  The link is to a plug-in that claims to be able to generate `@XmlElementWrapper` annotations into the model.  If that plug-in doesn't work try searching for something similar.

Comment: Have you considered my previous comment?

Comment: @mostruash - Yes, did you get what I said about `@XmlElementWrapper`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26195/discussion-between-mostruash-and-blaise-doughan)